# Why does the Bitcoin pool reject my Antminer D3 shares?

Tags: mining-hardware, antminer

I hope somebody can help, since I have received my antminer D3 and connected it to the antpool, all my shares are getting rejected.
I am mining bitcoins but all of them are getting rejected.
I have uploaded a screenshot below.

Somebody knows what is the solution to fix this problem.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You cannot mine Bitcoin with D3.
You can only mine Dash with a D3.

Answer (score 2):

The [Antminer D3 spec](https://shop.bitmain.com/productDetail.htm?pid=00020170718203947438V537cuy7067F) states that it is a miner for the **X11** hashing algorithm.

Bitcoin uses SHA-256d as its hashing algorithm. The Antminer D3 cannot mine Bitcoin, but only X11 based currencies such as Dash.

[image]